# Switching keyboardType clears TextField text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

I just found a bug in an app I'm working on that seems to be specific to iOS 8, but I can't figure out the cause or a solution, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The issue is I have a view where the user inputs a passcode. When the text field is active, initially we display a number pad, with a button above the keyboard to switch to the alphabet keyboard. Here's the code for the button tap for that button to toggle between a qwerty keyboard and number pad.

`UIButton *toggleButton = sender;

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 8.0f)
{
    [self.passcodeField resignFirstResponder];
}

if (self.passcodeField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad) {
    self.passcodeField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad;
    [toggleButton setTitle: @"123" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    self.passcodeField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [toggleButton setTitle: @"ABC" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 8.0f)
{
    [self.passcodeField becomeFirstResponder];
}

[self.passcodeField reloadInputViews];`
```

The problem is if I type "123" into the number pad, switch to the qwerty keyboard, as soon as I type a single character, it clears the original input and replaces it with the new characters rather than appending it. I'm not sure why as there is no code in my view controller that would clear the text in passcodeField. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Is your text field secure?
If so, I think your problem is with calling `resignFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder`.
This is natural behaviour of a secure text field, when it activates it erases all text previously entered.

Comment: "This is not a bug, it's a feature!" :)

Comment: It's not a very nice feature. It is a secure text field, so that's probably the problem. Any ideas on a work around for this? If I don't make the calls to resign and become firstResponder, in iOS8 the keyboard doesn't change, so that has to be there.

Comment: I totally understand you, we had the same issue with simply switching from insecure to secure mode programmatically. As I googled it, there is no "clean" solution, but you always can remember the text before resigning and assign it afterwards.